# What is "e" in onChange(e)?

Tags: javascript

I've been using it for quite some time but i still don't know - what is the `e` object you have access to when passing it over to `onChange` or `onSubmit`?

Comment: Just log it to your console and you will see exactly what it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It depends. Generally it's information about the event.

- For `onsubmit` and `onchange` it conforms to the `Event` interface.

  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/submit
  - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change
- For `onclick` it's a `MouseEvent`.

  You can look up the specifics on MDN.

Comment: The last time I dupevoted and answered the question I was told that it would be unfair to other answerers, just saying ...

Comment: @JonasWilms Generally speaking I think that questions should *not* be answered if they are duplicates. That said, Daniel had answered this *before* closing it. While it may or may not be the case, I saw that he closed it shortly after I flagged it as a dupe, so he may not have realized it was a dupe when answering. I suppose the follow-up question would be "Should I delete my correct/good answer to a duplicate question after it's been closed?"